# Cannot resolve symbol AsyncLoadTasks error in Android sample code

Tags: android, rest, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use some sample in order to use Google Drive REST API v3, but I keep getting a "Cannot resolve symbol AsyncLoadTasks" error when I copy across the code from [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java) (minus some interface stuff I didn't want to use).  How can I get the Async lines to work correctly?

Also, if it helps, below is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()  // For google-play-services is not on Maven Central.
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev48-1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.3.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-google-api-client.txt'
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can find AsyncLoadTasks in the same folder: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android

Comment: @SergeyGlotov Ah yes of course, why didn't I see that!  Thank you.